# How to easily get the unmatched condition in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a "server" table which has a column named 'SN' in mysql, when do query to retrive servers with some sns from 'sn1' to 'sn10000', we can:

```
select * from server where sn in ('sn1','sn2','sn3',...'sn10000');
```

If there is only one sn in 'sn1'-'sn10000' which not exists in database, then the query above will retrive 9999 rows of result.

The question is how can I easily get which one in 'sn1'-'sn10000' is not exists in database except the additional work, such as handling the result with shell script etc.

I have an ugly sql like below can use:

```
select * from (select 'sn1' as sn 
        union select 'sn2' 
        union select 'sn3'
        ....
        union select 'sn10000') as SN 
where not exists (select id from server where server.sn=SN.sn);
```

Is Anyone has other better methods? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is perfectly fine for the intended use, but [on MySQL the NOT IN and LEFT JOIN/IS NULL are more effecient that NOT EXISTS](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/).  Here are your alternatives:

### NOT IN

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (          SELECT 'sn1' as sn 
        UNION ALL SELECT 'sn2' 
        UNION ALL SELECT 'sn3'
        ....
        UNION ALL SELECT 'sn10000') as SN 
 WHERE sn.sn NOT IN (SELECT s.id FROM SERVER s)
```

### LEFT JOIN/IS NULL

```
   SELECT s.id
     FROM SERVER s
LEFT JOIN (          SELECT 'sn1' as sn 
           UNION ALL SELECT 'sn2' 
           UNION ALL SELECT 'sn3'
           ....
           UNION ALL SELECT 'sn10000') as SN ON SN.sn = s.id
    WHERE sn.sn IS NULL
```

You might notice I used `UNION ALL`, rather than `UNION` - `UNION` removes duplicates (which won't happen in your example), making it slower so `UNION ALL` is a better choice.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I wonder there is no any simple method without using temporary table...

Answer (score 1):

Stick your sn1, sn2, sn3... sn10000 values in a temporary table, and then use Joins.

```
Select server.* from server inner join tempt on (tempt.value = server.sn)
```

will give you the ones that match, where as

```
Select sn.* from server right outer join tempt on (tempt.value = server.sn) 
where server.somefield is Null
```

should take care of finding the missing ones.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks like there is no way to achieve this without temporary table. The method proposed in my question is indeed using the temporary table too.
Thanks a lot.